# I'm trying to sort an NSMutableArray of objects by a field of type double

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

the code I'm currently trying doesn't give any errors but after it runs nothing is sorted. This is my first time in objective-c so I'm hoping there's something obvious here that I'm missing.

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceOfPlace" ascending:true] ;
[surroundingRestaurants sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: I think this question is more about the difference between a method that modifies its input and one that outputs its result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` returns a new array, rather than modifying the original array. If your object is an [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), this is your only option, so you should store it back in the original array:

```
surroundingRestaurants = [surroundingRestaurants sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

If, however, you have an [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can use `sortUsingDescriptors`, and it will modify the original array:

```
[surroundingRestaurants sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

By they way, `[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]` can be written more succinctly as `@[sortDescriptor]`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the mutable version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean...

`NSArray *mySortedArray = [surroundingRestaurants sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];`

Refer to the docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

Comment: okay so i need a destination. yes I see that because it's in brackets ints a function acting on the array "surroundingRestaurants" right? I need said array sorted so could I do

    [surroundingRestaurants = surroundingRestaurants sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

Comment: And the surroundingRestaurants is changing size all the time. But I tried what I just said, and obviously I can't return an array to the type mutable array. So I'm not sure how to handle that. Have my sorted array by declared as NSArray and just keep assigning it a new array of objects? Can it change like that?

Comment: The method you are using RETURNS a sorted array. It does NOT modify the array you pass in.